# rails db:migrate in Procfile causes app to crash in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I include `web: rails:db:migrate` in my Procfile it crashes my rails application. When I run `rails db:migrate` using the Heroku console via browser, it works just fine.

```
2018-01-20T08:01:30.465226+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate`

2018-01-20T08:01:34.612837+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-01-20T08:01:34.206214 #4]  INFO -- : [SKYLIGHT] [1.5.0] Skylight agent enabled

2018-01-20T08:01:34.612854+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-01-20T08:01:34.576132 #4] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(8624398319468495445)[0m

2018-01-20T08:01:34.612855+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-01-20T08:01:34.589800 #4] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (1.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC[0m

2018-01-20T08:01:34.612857+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-01-20T08:01:34.597079 #4] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (1.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

2018-01-20T08:01:34.612858+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-01-20T08:01:34.604685 #4] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m

2018-01-20T08:01:34.612859+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-01-20T08:01:34.606578 #4] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m

2018-01-20T08:01:34.612860+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-01-20T08:01:34.607768 #4] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT pg_advisory_unlock(8624398319468495445)[0m

2018-01-20T08:01:34.692625+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2018-01-20T08:01:34.670371+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

Comment: Please add the error details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Procfile`, `web` is for webserver, eg:

`web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`

In order to run migration when deploying to Heroku, you need to append this line to `Procfile`:

`release: rake db:migrate`

Comment: this fixed my problem :) thanks so much for the further explanation! much appreciated.